# GIT Read only access with access to specific files

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a private Repository configured on Bitbucket.org with several users with the permissions of Read/Write to the repository. 
We have built a solution over the past months and now will have to start deploying them to clients on a Agile Model. Where we would be adding new features to the existing code and then pull the new code after testing on the Client machine.

So what i feel can be done is to create a read only user for the repository and use it to only pull the latest tested branch of code to the client machine.

But the issues here is:

1. There is a large parameter file in the repository which is System specific. Meaning the parameter values for the Development machine will be different from the parameter values on the client machine) So when i pull the repo to the client machine, i will overwrite the parameter file. -- NO GOOD :( --
2. Several Logs will be created on client machine which will be overwritten on each pull with logs on Development machine.

Can i make a User (Readd Only) which has access to only specific files(Which i will define) and will only be able to pull those files on the client machine?

I am new to git technology and am willing to research more. Please share some relevant links,docs which can lead me to an answer myself.

Comment: Files which are deployment specific should arguably not be kept under version control. I'd recommend removing them from git and putting them in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry for my limited knowledge of Git here. but a quick google search on gitignore showed that we can put specific files which will be ignored by git.

Comment: Yes, you can tell git to ignore *adding* certain files. If you have already added them you will have to remove them because git won't stop tracking the files even if you add them to the ignore filter.

Comment: That is correct. You put them in `.gitignore` so that nobody will accidentally commit these files to git after you've removed them.

Comment: One Follow up question here:
There is one parameter file which contains URLs, Usernames, AWS Credentials etc specific to the machine the code is running on. This is a file that connects with rest of the code in the developed framework and will be needed in both (dev and production) machines. So if i gitignore this file, will that basically not mean that when i have to deploy the code for a new client, a simple git pull would not suffice, i will have to deploy the parameter file specifically?
Currently, i pull the repository on client machine and then configure the parameter file manually.

Comment: The customary way to handle configuration files with version control systems is to commit a template only. Your build and/or deploy scripts would then check if you have the "real" configuration file locally, and if not make a fresh copy from the template. This "real" configuration file would be ignored by the version control system so that you don't accidentally commit passwords or other such things into the repository. It would also stop the version control system from overwriting the file on servers or development machines if you change the template. Only the template will be replaced.

Comment: Ohh, i get the approach now. 
Make a template on repo
Configure the template on the specific machine
Keep the Template in git ignore to avoid accidental overwrite issues
?? @Lasse V. Karlsen

Comment: No, keep the real config in git ignore, the template should be tracked as normal.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the algo here. !!